# How to get Redux states in React-Router routerWillLeave()?

Tags: react-router, redux

I'm trying to get Redux state `this.props` from within routerWillLeave(). I'm using a decorated component to add the Lifecycle. `this` is referencing the wrong thing so `this.props` is undefined. I'm using react-router 1.0.0 rc4

```
@reactMixin.decorate(Lifecycle)
class AccountEditPage extends Component {

...

  routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {

    console.log(nextLocation);
    console.log(this.props);        

    const pattern = /accounts\/\d\/edit/i;

    if(!nextLocation.pathname.match(pattern)){
     return 'Your work is not saved! Are you sure you want to leave?';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minor abstraction breakage. You just need to bind `routerWillLeave`, either in the constructor or via a property initializer for now. We might try to improve this API a bit in the future.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, can you provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of code to follow up on Taion's correct answer.

Example in es6 constructor:

```
@reactMixin.decorate(Lifecycle)
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    /* ... */

    this.routerWillLeave = this.routerWillLeave.bind(this);  //bind the function to this scope
  }

  routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
    console.log(this.props);
  }
}
```